# PHP Array in MySQL IN() function?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is it possible to assign php array in MySQL IN() function? for example,

```
$numbers = array('8001254656','8886953265','88864357445','80021536245');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `number_table` WHERE `number` IN ($numbers)");
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet should help you out, as long as number is restricted to numbers.

```
<?php

// Generate a filtered comma-separated list of the numeric values in numbers.
// Non-numeric values might allow for SQL-injection bugs.
$SQL_numberList = implode(", ", array_filter($numbers, 'is_numeric'));
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `number_table` WHERE `number` IN ($SQL_numberList)");
```

For string arguments in the list you'll need to do something a little different.

Answer (score 1):

No. Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) first.